# Mark the output directory for a Java program

Tags: java

I have been creating a JavaIDE.
My IDE stores the byte codes in a directory named `bin` (after compiling the project) so the problem is whenever a project is made to run and when it outputs a file (let's say `data.txt`) by creating the file object as `new File("data.txt")` without any absolute path then, that file is stored in the bin directory. So, my question is: is there a way to mark any other directory as the output directory of the program in the command "java -?" or any property.

Like: `java -outdir out pack.Main`?

So that the file without any absolute path can be made to store in the directory named `out`.

Comment: You have to adjust the relative path, your project directory.

Comment: The path is simple from where you are executing `java.exe`, so you can just move to a different folder and then start `java.exe`.

Comment: Actually the problem is if I have to run pack.Main, then I have to set the working folder as the bin directory else it will not execute

Comment: Process p = Runtime.exec("java pack.Main", null, new File("projectpath//bin"))

Comment: Someone please answer

Comment: How about you invest some time to [edit] your question and include all the details? Maybe show some code, show some screenshots, the output, everything that helps answering the question. Improve the quality of your question, make it easier for people to help you. Avoid leaving out information such that this ping-pong back and forth is required. A question of high quality will also receive high quality answers.

Comment: This question can be well understood without showing codes or screenshots as no one can provide codes and screenshots on a question based on jvm. The one who knows java at master level will understand what I am trying to ask.

Comment: You can't change the current working directory from within Java. If you want files to appear in places other than the current working directory, you have to provide relative or absolute paths to the desired destination.

Comment: Yes. I know that but this will cause much difficulty in managing the output locations of files used by an application.

Comment: I was mainly proposing to add more details because you seem to change or add more requirements during the comments. So it seems that you did not put everything needed into the question. Also, it sounds like a XY question. Since you were explicitly asking for more attention and answers, this is what you can do from your side to receive more answers - improve the quality of your question. It is up to you if you agree to that or not, but I can tell you from my experience on this site that if you put more time into your question, you will get good answers faster.

Comment: Thank you for concern

Comment: But it don't think so that I can provide more details to it

Comment: @Arham It doesn't matter how much difficulty it causes. You don't have any choice.